# Variable keeps growing even if condition is not met

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, scroll

I'm trying to animate a div on scroll. The point is that the div's width must grow until it reaches 80vw and stop. This does happen, but my variable keeps on growing (it's being logged to the console) even if the >=outerWidth*0.8 condition isn't met. Thanks to this, whenever I get to 80vw and scroll up and then down, the width becomes Xvw.

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var outerHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
    var outerWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
    var scrollBottom = scrollTop + outerHeight;
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();


    console.log( growNaranja );
    if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop){ // scroll down
        if( naranjaWidth <= (outerWidth*0.8)  ){
            growNaranja = (naranja.outerWidth()*100) / outerWidth;
            growNaranja = growNaranja+(scrollTop*0.05);
            $('.grow.naranja').css( 'width', growNaranja + 'vw' );
        }
    } else { // scroll up
        if( naranjaWidth >= (outerWidth*0.1)  ){
            growNaranja = (naranja.outerWidth()*100) / outerWidth;
            $('.grow.naranja').css( 'width', growNaranja + 'vw' );
            growNaranja = growNaranja - ((lastScrollTop-scrollTop)*0.05);
            $('.grow.naranja').css( 'width', growNaranja + 'vw' );
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

You can see a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/j9m0o1Lw/2/).

Comment: Where exactly is `naranjaWidth` being defined? You're using it for comparison, but it's not actually a variable with any value.

Answer (score 1):

Revisited this one, it was bugging me. First, the code was all spaghetti. Second, there was really function duplication. You had a function for scrolling up and one for scrolling down, and you were using the last scrollTop to calculate the next scroll step. Instead, I've made a single scale function that gets called regardless. The value of the percentage scrolled is multiplied by the step factor, and that is added to the ORIGINAL element width. By doing this, I'm not worried about where I was just prior to the scroll, only where I am now.

So I made the scaleWidthEl an object constructor, and simply wrapped the naranja div in that. The actual code to create it is the first three lines, and could be reduced to:

```
var scaleNaranja = new ScaleWidthEl($('.grow.naranja'), 0.8);
```

The rest is self-contained, allowing changes to be made without affecting anything else.

```js
var maxElScale = 0.8;
var naranja = $('.grow.naranja');

var scaleNaranja = new ScaleWidthEl(naranja, maxElScale);



/***
 *  The rest of this is a black-box function, walled away from the main code
 * It's a personal peeve of mine that code gets garbled otherwise.
 ***/
function ScaleWidthEl(el, maxScale) {
  // I don't need a minScale, as I use the initial width for that
  this.el = el;
  this.vwConversion = (100 / document.documentElement.clientWidth);
  this.startingWidth = el.outerWidth();
  this.maxScale = maxScale;
  this.max = $(window).outerWidth() * this.maxScale;
  this.step = (this.max - this.startingWidth) / $(window).outerHeight();
  // for the sake of clarity, store a reference to `this` for
  //  any nested functions.
  var that = this;

  /**
   * function scaleEl
   *   handle the actual scaling of the element.
   *   Using a given step, we will simply add that
   *   to the element's current width, then update the CSS
   *   width property of the element.
   **/
  this.scaleEl = function() {
    // First, calculate the percentage of vertical scroll
    var winheight = $(window).height();
    var docheight = $(document).height();
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var trackLength = docheight - winheight;
    // gets percentage scrolled (ie: 80 NaN if tracklength == 0)
    var pctScrolled = Math.floor(scrollTop / trackLength * 100);
//    console.log(pctScrolled + '% scrolled')

    // Now, using the scrolled percentage, scale the div
    var tempWidth = this.startingWidth * this.vwConversion;
    tempWidth += pctScrolled * this.step;
    // I want to fix the max of the scale
    if (tempWidth > (this.maxScale * 100)) {
      tempWidth = this.maxScale * 100;
    }
    this.el.css('width', tempWidth + 'vw');
  };


  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    that.scaleEl();
  }).on("resize", function() {
    /**
     * In the case of a resize, we should
     *  recalculate min, max and step.
     **/
    that.min = $(window).outerWidth() * that.minScale;
    that.max = $(window).outerWidth() * that.maxScale;
    that.step = (that.max - that.min) / $(window).outerHeight();
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 10000px;
}

.grow {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.grow.gris {
  width: 35vw;
  z-index: 2;
  background: silver;
}

.grow.naranja {
  width: 10vw;
  z-index: 1;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="grow naranja"></div>
<!-- .naranja -->
```

Comment: @CaptainMagikarp, have you opened the console? The values are being constrained, in both directions. How does it strike you that the problem is not being solved?

Comment: The Size of the Div is inconsistent? It shouldn't go >80% if I understand correctly

Comment: That could be done, I suppose -- by saying in the if statement's else that the limit should be set to 80 if it happens to go wider. Same with the min. Hang on, I'll make that change.

Comment: That's weird. it's a function of the scroll action -- it approximates the 0.8 and 0.1 value. But if I try to do a hard-coded value set, it's running again. It seems to run to the viewport pixel width or something. Strange.

Comment: @Snowmonkey I think you're not getting at the problem (not as easily as I am), if you scroll down until you reach 80vw and keep going down, then scroll up just a little, and then down again you'll see what the issue is (the orange div will grow way past 80vw)